I'm getting a syntax error but I don't think theirs anything wrong
I am needing to write a program to make a right facing arrow but on my first line and its giving me a syntax error But I don't see anything wrong with it, I'm guessing its because I'm using the star which means multiply.  I'm going to how 5 rows for the arrow but I'm just starting out with the first row.  Below is the information given to me and then  the code I have written so far.
Ex: If the input is: *  #
Then the output is:

      #
******##
******###
******##
      #

base_char=input(*)         # line 1
head_char=input(#)         # line 2
                           # line 3
row1='      ' + head_char  # line 4
                           # line 5
print(row1)                # line 6

displayed error:
base_char=input(*)
                 ^
syntax error: invalid syntax

I wasn't expecting any trouble with my code so far.  I think its the star symbol that's causing me trouble.  I think ill run into the same problem once it notices the # on the second line after I figure out the first line.

what is your code then. its hard to tell what the problem is without seeing it ;)

Please create a proper [mre], and [edit] your question to format it properly. Also copy-paste (as text) the full and complete error output into the question as well.

As a probable hint: input(*)? Don't you mean input('*')? What are you really supposed to do? What is the input for? What tutorials do you follow, or what books are you reading? What do they say about the input function? And please take some time to read about the input function.

Adding quotes helped getting rid of the syntax error but now I'm getting an EOF error reading line 1.  I'm supposed to make a right facing arrow where I use * as the body of the arrow and the # as the head of the arrow.  So far I'm not given really any info on how to do this, this is my first semester of programming in college so this is very new to me.  @Someprogrammerdude

Bring your assignment here in its original word. Or maybe you need to ask your tutor for help first.

I added the information about my assignment to the text.  @ChrisFu

Size of the arrow is fixed as 9x5 ?

yes it is @ChrisFu

The input function takes string as an argument.
It should be base_char=input("*") and head_char=input("#").
Updated answer to the edited question:
It seems like you were trying to give * and # as input. Input function allows user to input a string from the terminal. It also takes an optional argument (string type) which promts the user in the terminal. Here, I believe what you wanted to achieve was something like this: base_char=input("Enter base character.") and head_char=input("Enter head character") to which you would give * and # as input.

With your added info, it seems that the character "*" and "#" should be input by a user. So the related code should be:
base_char = input()
head_char = input()

Strings you may write inside input(...) would be prompts, and they are not required for your assignment.
